# Android billingHelper.dispose() Usage

Tags: android, in-app-billing, dispose

How important is it to dispose of the helper? Also is it always needed to be placed on activity.destroy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per android documentation, `If you don’t unbind, the open service connection could cause your device’s performance to degrade.`

It is generally a good practice to unbind all the listeners once the task is no more needed. This improves your device battery utilization of the application.

As a Mobile performance engineer, i have come across several applications where not turning off the listener or service, impacting the app battery utilization to a significant level.

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
   super.onDestroy();
   if (mHelper != null) mHelper.dispose();
   mHelper = null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, how about if you have multiple activities calling into BillingHelper?

Comment: I use an external class so other Activities can re-use it, I placed your snippet in the Finally block of the method.